# VBA define the Pivot Table filter with cell values - time

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I am trying to use vba to define the Pivot Table tile date range whenever I update the data in the control box.

[P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9TQL.png)

However, it only works when I put 12:00 in the control box, not any other times.

[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ajJ.png)

Any one knows why? Is it because the data type being defined? I've tried string / string / single / double and even tried to convert the data type in the control box or change the data type in the data source, none of those seems to be working. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

```
Dim UpperTime As Date
Dim LowerTime As Date
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C5")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
       UpperTime = Range("C4").ValueLowerTime = Range("C5").Value
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Sched Start Time"). _ClearLabelFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Sched Start Time"). _
PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:=UpperTime, Value2:=LowerTime
```

Comment: I've had similar problems with dates. Have you tried `Value1:=CLng(UpperTime),Value2:=CLng(LowerTime)`, (Or other CASTs?)